# Loading opengl texture using Boost.GIL

Tags: c++, opengl, boost

I wrote a simple app that load model using OpenGL, Assimp and Boost.GIL.

My model contains a PNG texture. When I load it using GIL and render it through OPENGL I got a wrong result. Thank of powel of codeXL, I found my texture loaded in OpenglGL is completely different from the image itself.

Here is a similar question and I followed its steps but still got same mistake.

Here are my codes:

```
// --------- image loading
std::experimental::filesystem::path path(pathstr);
gil::rgb8_image_t img;
if (path.extension() == ".jpg" || path.extension() == ".jpeg" || path.extension() == ".png")
{
    if (path.extension() == ".png")
        gil::png_read_and_convert_image(path.string(), img);
    else
        gil::jpeg_read_and_convert_image(path.string(), img);

    _width = static_cast<int>(img.width());
    _height = static_cast<int>(img.height());

    typedef decltype(img)::value_type pixel;

    auto srcView = gil::view(img);
    //auto view = gil::interleaved_view(
    //  img.width(), img.height(), &*gil::view(img).pixels(), img.width() * sizeof pixel);

    auto pixeldata = new pixel[_width * _height];

    auto dstView = gil::interleaved_view(
        img.width(), img.height(), pixeldata, img.width() * sizeof pixel);

    gil::copy_pixels(srcView, dstView);
}

// ---------- texture loading
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle());
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
        image.width(), image.height(),
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        reinterpret_cast<const void*>(image.data()));
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And my texture is:
[image: original texture]

When it runs, my codeXL debugger reports me that the texture became:
[image: texture in opengl]

all other textures of this model went wrong too.

Answer (score 3):

Technically this is a FAQ, asked already several times. Essentially you're running into an alignment issue. By default (you can change it) OpenGL expects image rows to be aligned on 4 byte boundaries. If your image data doesn't match this, you get this skewed result. Adding a call to `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` right before the call to `glTexImage…` will do the trick *for you*. *Of course you should retrieve the actual alignment from the image metadata.*

The image being "upside down" is caused by OpenGL putting the origin of textures into the *lower left* (if all transformation matrices are left at default or have positive determinant). That is unlike most image file formats (but not all) which have it in the *upper* left. Just flip the vertical texture coordinate and you're golden.

Comment: it's helpful to me!!THANK YOU！！